# What to do when users generate the same action several time waiting for download?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, web-services

I am designing an IPhone application. User search something. We grab data from the net. Then we update the table.

THe pseudocode would be

```
[DoThisAtbackground ^{
  LoadData ();
  [DoThisAtForeground ^{
    UpdateTableAndView();
  }];
}];
```

What about if before the first search is done the user search something else.

What's the industry standard way to solve the issue?

1. Keep track which thread is still running and only update the table
   when ALL threads have finished?
2. Update the view every time a thread finish?

How exactly we do this?

Comment: Kick the user, or hit him with something heavy :) I hate these impatient bastards ;) Good question, though.

Comment: Well, what about auto complete? Users type pretty fast and each time they type they pull something from the web.

Comment: I have a system where we keep track number of threads. Still buggy. I can post that as an answer.

Comment: Disable (and change color of) any buttons whose action is in progress.

Comment: That's some good idea. I really want to avoid terminating any thread. Every time a thread ended I do something like updating thread counter or saving managed object context. Terminating thread prematurely will introduce hard to debug issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html). Apple thinks it's pretty important all application behave in about the same way, so they've written an extensive document about these kind of issues.

In the guidelines there are two things that are relevant to your question:

- [**Make Search Quick and Rewarding**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW14): "When possible, also filter remote data while users type. Although filtering users' typing can result in a better search experience, be sure to inform them and give them an opportunity to opt out if the response time is likely to delay the results by more than a second or two."
- [**Feedback**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Principles/Principles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH5-SW5): "Feedback acknowledges people’s actions and assures them that processing is occurring. People expect immediate feedback when they operate a control, and they appreciate status updates during lengthy operations."

Although there is of course a lot of nonsense in these guidelines, I think the above points are actually a good idea to follow. As a user, I expect something to happen when searching, and when you update the view every time a thread is finished, the user will see the fastest response. Yes, it might be results the user doesn't want, but something is happening! For example, take the Safari web browser in iOS: Google autocomplete displays results even when you're typing, and not just when you've finished entering your search query.

So I think it's best to go with your second option.

Answer (score 2):

If you're performing the REST request for data to your remote server you can always cancel the request and start the new one without updating the table, which is a way to go. Requests that have the time to finish will update UI and the others won't. For example use ASIHTTPRequest

```
- (void)serverPerformDataRequestWithQuery:(NSString *)query andDelegate:(__weak id <ServerDelegate)delegate {
  [currentRequest setFailedBlock:nil];
  [currentRequest cancel];
  currentRequest = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:kHOST];
  [currentRequest startAsynchronous];
}
```

Let me know if you need an answer for the local SQLite databases too as it is much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSOperationQueue` to cancel all pending operations, but it still would not cancel the existing operation.  You would still have to implement something to cancel the existing operation... which also works to early-abort the operations in the queue.

I usually prefer straight GCD, unless there are other benefits in my use cases that are a better fit for `NSOperationQueue`.

Also, if your loading has an external cancel mechanism, you want to cancel any pending I/O operations.

If the operations are independent, consider a concurrent queue, as it will allow the newer request to execute simultaneously as the other(s) are being canceled.

Also, if they are all I/O, consider if you can use `dispatch_io` instead of blocking a thread.  As [Monk](http://www.usanetwork.com/series/monk/) would say, "You'll thank me later."

Consider something like this:

```
- (void)userRequestedNewSearch:(SearchInfo*)searchInfo {
    // Assign this operation a new token, that uniquely identifies this operation.
    uint32_t token = [self nextOperationToken];

    // If your "loading" API has an external abort mechanism, you want to keep
    // track of the in-flight I/O so any existing I/O operations can be canceled
    // before dispatching new work.

    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        // Try to load your data in small pieces, so you can exit as early as
        // possible.  If you have to do a monolithic load, that's OK, but this
        // block will not exit until that stops.  
        while (! loadIsComplete) {
            if ([self currentToken] != token) return;
            // Load some data, set loadIsComplete when loading completes
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // One last check before updating the UI...
            if ([self currentToken] != token) return;

            // Do your UI update operations
        });
    });

}
```

It will early-abort any operation that is not the last one submitted.  If you used `NSOperationQueue` you could call `cancelAllOperations` but you would still need a similar mechanism to early-abort the one that is currently executing.